# Extension wrapper malloc allocator for C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, malloc, wrapper, allocator

Apparently there is a “malloc_allocator” provided with gcc for use with STL. It simply wraps malloc and free. There is also a hook for an out-of-memory handler. Where can I find more about it? Where can I find its header file? I’m using gcc 4.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Is](http://archpub20.cs.ccu.edu.tw/cgi-bin/dwww?type=file&location=/usr/share/doc/gcc-3.4-base/libstdc%2B%2B/html_user/malloc__allocator_8h-source.html) this something you want? You will need to include and pass in an object as the STL object's allocator template parameter.

Comment: Yes! This is what I want. But why is <new> included? And where can I find this file on my system - or - where did you find this file?

Comment: @prasoon99: A google search brought this up. `<new>` is a system header. I am tempted to believe that this is present on your system already, try to look for the file in `include\ext`.

Comment: My question was WHY is <new> included in the file. I guess it is there because std::bad_alloc() is used.

Comment: Next question: if I allocate:

std::vector<T, malloc_allocator<T> > *v 
       = new std::vector<T, malloc_allocator<T> > (5)

Then what is the correct way of deleting v?

Comment: `delete v;` should do it. Note the implementation will take care of calling the appropriate `malloc_allocator` based de-allocation function via the `vector`'s dtor.

Answer (score 0):

The out-of-memory handler in c++ is defined via `set_new_handler`, which might be in the `<new>` header, but I'm not sure.